# Is there a way to change the classname in the junit report while using playwright?

Tags: javascript, junit, playwright

after I ran playwright tests, junit test report is generated as shown below

```
<testsuite name="/somefile.spec.ts" timestamp="...." hostname="chromium" tests="3" failures="0" skipped="0" time="66.849" errors="0"\>

<testcase name="can comment on a fabric page" classname="add-page-comment.spec.ts" time="20.884"\><testcase ... \>

</testsuite\>
```

and I would like alter the `classname` in the `testcase` to my wish as shown below (from `add-page-comment.spec.ts` to `add-page-comment spec file`).

```
<testcase name="can comment on a fabric page" classname="add-page-comment spec file" time="20.884"\>
```

is there a way to do it?